# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: PlatformTransactionManager running Junit Tests in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
When I run the application in normal mode, it seems to work OK

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven and I am not using JPA, jdbcTemplate instead

I have this JUnit test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes={PersistenceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JdbcMetricsRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    MetricsRepository jdbcMetricsRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetAllDeviceEventsWithAlarm() throws DataAccessException, SQLException {

        //jdbcMetricsRepository.getIberiaDataTab1();

        assertNotNull (jdbcMetricsRepository.getIberiaDataTab1());
    }
}
```

But when I run the test I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:284)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getIberiaDataTab1(Unknown Source)
    at com.iberia.repository.JdbcMetricsRepositoryTests.testGetAllDeviceEventsWithAlarm(JdbcMetricsRepositoryTests.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Here the persistenceConfig

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
@EnableTransactionManagement /* Defines a Bean Post-Processor (proxies @Transactional bean) */
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Value("${db.driver.class.name}")
    private String dbDriverClassName;

    @Value("${db.jdbc.url}")
    private String dbJdbcUrl;

    @Value("${db.user}")
    private String dbUser ;

    @Value("${db.pwd}")
    private String dbPwd;


    @Value("${db.pool.size}")
    private Integer dbPoolSize;

    @Value("${db.minimum.idle}")
    private Integer dbMinimumIdle;

    @Bean
    public  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }


    @Bean 
    public UserRepository userRepository() {
        return new JdbcUserRepository();
    }


    @Bean 
    public RemoteUnitEventRepository remoteUnitEventRepository() {
        return new JdbcRemoteUnitEventRepository();
    }


    @Bean 
    public MetricsRepository metricsRepository() {
        return new JdbcMetricsRepository();
    }




    /**
     * Creates an in-memory "ideefe" database populated 
     * with test data for fast testing
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(getDbPoolSize());
        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
        config.setDriverClassName(getDbDriverClassName());
        config.setJdbcUrl(getDbJdbcUrl());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", getDbUser());
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", getDbPwd());

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    public String getDbDriverClassName() {
        return dbDriverClassName;
    }


    public String getDbJdbcUrl() {
        return dbJdbcUrl;
    }


    public String getDbUser() {
        return dbUser;
    }


    public String getDbPwd() {
        return dbPwd;
    }


    public int getDbPoolSize() {
        return dbPoolSize;
    }


    public int getDbMinimumIdle() {
        return dbMinimumIdle;
    } 
}
```

Here my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency> 
            <groupId>oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.5.3</version> -->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: And PersistenceConfig would look like...?

Comment: You need to have a @Bean method to return an instance of PlatformTransactionManager. Refer http://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring for example

Comment: but I am not using JPA

Comment: So you aren't using auto config in your test and still expect spring boot to auto configure everything. Why are you trying so hard NOT to use Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've redifined your datasource, you can define your PlatformTransactionManger by define the bean bellow

```
@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    final DataSourceTransactionManager txManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);

    return txManager;
}
```

Comment: but I am not using JPA

Comment: For those who need a DataSouce but don't mind using h2 (an embedded in-memory database): `JdbcDataSource dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();        dataSource.setURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test"); txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);` and add to your pom.xml: `<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.199</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
`